# Total blob count of all folders inside an Azure container

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure container.
There are 5000+ *folders* inside it.
Each folder has  close to million+ blobs..

Storage Explorer/Folder Statistics is taking too much time.

I want to calculate all the blobs inside each folder programmatically(c#).
Is this feasible ?
Please guide.
Thanks.

Comment: i don't know how good the performance on the solution provided is, but i usually like to use data factory to deal with these types of situations where you need something very long-running and there's lots of data involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Powershell, I have used to check all files inside blob with a certain timestamp and generate an excel report of storage space.
A similar concept can be applied with an outer loop across all containers.

```
    ## Declaring the variables
$number_of_days_threshold = 0
$current_date = get-date
$date_before_blobs = $current_date.AddDays(-$number_of_days_threshold)

## Storage account details
$storage_account_name = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
$storage_account_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$container = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

## Creating Storage context for Source, destination and log storage accounts
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage_account_name -StorageAccountKey $storage_account_key
$blob_list = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $context -Container $container
$output = @()

## Iterate through each blob
foreach($blob_iterator in $blob_list){
   $blob_date = [datetime]$blob_iterator.LastModified.UtcDateTime 
   if($blob_date -le $date_before_blobs) {
   # $blob_iterator | %{$_.ICloudBlob.BreakLease()}
   # Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container -Blob $blob_iterator.Name -Context $context
   $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
      "Name" = $blob_iterator.Name
      "LastModified" = $blob_iterator.LastModified
      "Length" = ($blob_iterator.Length)
   }
  $output += $customObject
   }
}
$output | Select `
     Name,
     LastModified,
     Length | export-csv -Path 'F:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```